# Error running Unit Tests for .NET MAUI Apps with .NET 6 RC2

Tags: .net, maui

Running `dotnet test` on a `net6` unit test project that references a project using .NET MAUI (`<UseMaui>true</UseMaui>`) throws the following error:

```sh
Testhost process exited with error: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version 
The framework 'Microsoft.Maui.Core', version '**FromWorkload**' (x64) was not found.
```

This error is happening with [.NET 6 Release Candidate 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-release-candidate-2/?WT.mc_id=mobile-0000-bramin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known-issue in .NET 6 RC2:

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/21845

Currently, `dotnet test` does not yet work for projects using [`dotnet workload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload-list?WT.mc_id=mobile-0000-bramin)s. Since .NET MAUI is installed as a .NET Workload, this means that `dotnet test` will not yet work for .NET MAUI apps.

**Update**: The [.NET MAUI team has fixed the issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/3017). This means using `dotnet test` on .NET MAUI projects will begin working in the next release, .NET MAUI Preview 10.

Comment: Still not working with MAUI Blazor in the latest preview